# How to trigger only one event at a time on textarea

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code.

**jQuery:**

```
 $("textarea").bind('change paste', function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      //event.preventDefault(); //It prevent text to be written
      alert("event = " + event.type);
 });
```

When I type anything and click outside, it works fine, only `change` event triggers.

But If I paste some text, `paste` event triggers and on clicking outside the `change` event triggers.
I want only one event to be fired. I tried `stopPropagation` but no success.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/wk7uwer0/1/)

Comment: They are 2 separate events, not chained together, so there is no propagation.  Remove the listener if you want to stop it or create a flag.

Comment: yeah @JeremyMiller is right, i would also try to do it with a flag that indicates if data was pasted and in result skip the change not very nice but works